# question of partition in double integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, partitions-for-integration

in the definition of double integral,what the first to do is to divide region into small subrectangles . my question is :do these partitions have to be rectangles? for example ,when dealing with polar coordinates,region is divided into many small polar rectangles which are not rectangles.so can I use other shape to divide a region ,for exmple:parallelgram or triangle ,Are these also called  double integral? if these are also double integral why does the definition of double integral only use subrectangle for partition

Comment: You're free to use any kind of reasonable partition so long as you correctly [account for](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) the associated area element. (e.g. in polar coordinates, $dx\,dy=r\,dr\,d\theta$) Using parallelograms instead of rectangles doesn't change much, since both shapes' areas depend on the same parameters. Meanwhile triangles are halves of parallelograms.

Comment: Polar coordinates still use rectangles for a partition. The region of integration is in $(r,\theta)$-space, not the $xy$-plane.